# PHP automatic array key quoter

Tags: php, lazy-evaluation

I'm working on a large codebase that doesn't have quotes around any array keys, e.g. `$_GET[page]`.

Does anyone have a script/regex that programmatically adds quotes to array keys for PHP?

---

**update**

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
egrep -lRZ "\.php" . | \
    xargs -0 -l sed -i -e "s/\$\([a-zA-Z_]\+\)\[\([a-zA-Z_]\+\)\]/$\1['\2']/g"
```

This only handles one-dimensional arrays.

Comment: I hope you shot the original programmer in the face!

Comment: The regex would have to basically re-create PHP's parser. Highly incredibly painful.

Comment: Be careful to check if any of the keys actually are comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hated doing this in the past. This will cover all but severe edge cases and multidimentional arrays. Either use `preg_replace` or something that allows regex for mass replace in all files (like Dreamweaver).

```
\$(\w+)\[(\w+)\]
```

Replace like so (`\#`, where `#` is the match offset):

```
$\1['\2']
```

I believe Dreamweaver's replace syntax is:

```
$$1['$2']
```

Multidimentional might work with (after you run the above):

```
\['(\w+)'\]\[(\w+)\]

['$1']['$2']
```

And finally, inspired by @MarcB's comment, in theory you could use [PHP::Tokenizer](http://php.net/tokenizer). See [the example](http://php.net/tokenizer.examples) and change the case statment to trigger on `T_ARRAY` and alter the array to conform before outputting it (and every other part of the file). If all works well, you'd get a new file, which you could then loop into [`SPL::DirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/class.directoryiterator) and update all files in one go (now and in the future).

Comment: I'm using sed, so i escaped the backreferences... `sed -e 's/\$\(\w+\)\[\(\w+\)\]/$\1['\2']/g'`   but it doesn't seem to capture the pattern $foo[bar]

Comment: @nnyby, wouldn't escaped backreferences be `sed -e 's/\$\(\w+\)\[\(\w+\)\]/$\\1['\\2']/g'`? You may also need to doubly escape the backslashes form the command line? `sed -e 's/\\$\\(\\w+)\\[\\(\\w+)\\]/$\\1['\\2']/g'` I'm unfamilliar with `sed` sorry :P

Comment: this replaces correctly... `sed -e "s/\$\([a-z]\+\)\[\([a-z]\+\)\]/$\1['\2']/g"`  now I just need to run it on all the files...

Comment: @nnyby, just make sure you check the replacements since there's a slight chance it could cause syntax errors.

Comment: here's what i ended up doing: `egrep -lRZ "\.php" . | xargs -0 -l sed -i -e "s/\$\([a-zA-Z_]\+\)\[\([a-zA-Z_]\+\)\]/$\1['\2']/g"`   thanks for your help!